# Community wiki checkbox

Tags: support, wiki, community-wiki

I thought I remembered there being a community wiki checkbox when creating a question or editing an existing one.  I created a question with the intention of making it community wiki but can not find a way to convert it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nevermind, I found the answer:

[Should the community wiki police be shut down?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392/should-the-community-wiki-police-be-shut-down/7183#7183)